# Custom error messages not working with Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I have trouble getting custom error messages to work with Spring 3.2. Here is my configs:

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.."})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.."})
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslator jpaExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean
    public FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory> entityManagerFactory(
            DataSource ds, JpaVendorAdapter jva) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.." });
        factoryBean.setDataSource(ds);
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jva);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory  emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter =
                new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
        converters.add(converter);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

And here's messages_en_US.properties file:

```
Pattern.userdto.email=Invalid email.
Pattern=Invalid syntax.
```

UserDTO class:

```
public final class UserDTO {

    @Size(min = MIN_EMAIL_LENGTH, max = MAX_EMAIL_LENGTH)
    @Pattern(regexp = EMAIL_PATTERN)
    private String email;

    ...

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    ...
}
```

Validation is triggered using javax.validation.Valid annotation.

I'm expecting that this would print out "Invalid email" when the given email doesn't match the pattern, but I'm getting "Invalid syntax" message.

Comment: How are you triggering validation? And how is your validator linked to the message source you configured? Have you set up a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` referring to this message source?

Comment: Validation is triggered using javax.validation.Valid annotation and I have updated my question to include my whole configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started working after changing message key to:

```
Pattern.userDTO.email
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the key of the message to be used within the `@Pattern` constraint:

```
...
@Pattern(regexp = EMAIL_PATTERN, message = "Pattern.userdto.email")
private String email;
...
```

Otherwise the default key is used (which is "{javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}").

Comment: I thought http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html would have resolved the message automatically without specifying the message Pattern.userdto.email on the pattern annotation

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Can such a resolver really be used together with Spring's Bean Validation support? I didn't find any example for that.

Comment: Got it working by changing key in message properties file to Pattern.userDTO.email